# Routing to HTTPS and Non www to www using .htaccess on an AWS Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite

I'm having a bit of an issue with my website on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk (and on a load balancer).

I want to redirect all traffic from:

https://...

http://...

www.mysite.com

mysite.com

**to**

https://www...

What I have is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This seems to work as there is a lot of documentation on the issue with mod_rewrite and load balancer health checkers.

But obviously the rule misses the case where the user may go nakedly in via - "https://MYDOMAIN" - in which case I don't get the redirect happening.

I tried adding the third line here:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But this seems to cause a redirect loop and results in a 503 error.

Has anyone had any luck here?

I've found a lot of threads on forcing HTTP -> HTTPS but none if any that did both. And the ones I have found resulted in the 503 I speak of. Perhaps my setting on my elastic beanstalk are a little off? Or is there something else I'm missing.

Thanks for any help.

Greg

Comment: Correction - I've been able to deploy the above and it works - but the non-www to www part doesn't seem to take affect.

Comment: Does www.yoursite.com works ? Also have you tried aws route 53 ?

Comment: www redirects correctly to https://www. Both www and non www are pointing to my load balancer on Route53